# iOS: Animate subview without calling layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

In layoutSubviews i layout my child views into appropriate positions, and for some of them apply some transformation. Now i want to make on this subviews repeatable scale animation to draw attention. But, when i launch animation with [UIView animate....], with changing transform property - fired layoutSubviews method, which conflict with animation (it override transform and animation not played).

Is there any good way (without bool flags) to handle this behavior?

Example:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    myChildView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake....;
}

- (void)animate {
    CGAffineTransform originalTransform = myChildView.transform;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:4];
                         //next line of code produce calling layoutSubviews
                         myChildView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.15f, 1.15f);
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         myChildView.transform = originalTransform; 
                         //after this also called layoutSubviews
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I have encountered this issue. I override the method `viewDidLayoutSubviews` inside the view controller to control the animation.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
     // This method will be called after subview's layoutSubviews.
     if (self.shouldAnimated) {
        // Do animation at here.
     }
}
```

However, this is just a dirty solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you would do better to not use layoutSubviews. Instead create and position and transform your subviews either inside the init method or a custom method called from the init.

Answer (score 1):

I meet this problem also. And I add another view(called subView) as a subview, and add the myChildView to subView. This will not trigger the layoutSubviews of superview when I change the transform of myChildView. And why, you can see this [UIView/CALayer: Transform triggers layoutSubviews in superview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24632876/uiview-calayer-transform-triggers-layoutsubviews-in-superview).

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any good way (without bool flags) to handle this behavior?

Yes. Rid off "layoutSubviews" method and set transform for children views in another method.

```
[self.parentView setUpChildrenViews];
...
[self.parentView animate];
```